# Waf, trouble adding manual dependencies

Tags: python, waf

I have a target in `waf`, which depends on multiple other files. There is a program which lists
those dependencies, and I want to use it, and pass to `waf`. I.e, if I have a target `T`, there
is a program which lists all the dependencies for `T`. But I'm not clear as to how to pass this
to `bld.add_manual_dependency()`.

A single file as dependency seems to be working fine:

```
bld.add_manual_dependency(bld.path.find_or_declare('T'), bld.path.find_resource('Dep1'))
```

But if I pass a list as the second argument, seems to accept, but doesnt work!.
I want to know how to pass multiple files (not `ant_glob()`, but selected by the program).

Comment: Hi, can you be a little more specific regarding your need ?
waf has a system of tools, with task generators, that can scan for file dependencies. You could ask for the external program to provide the names of the dependencies, and resolve them to nodes in the source folder.

Comment: visiting this after a long time!, @Zouloub - ok, I think I was stuck in the names->nodes I think! because the external program lists the names on `stdout`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want the target to be produced from the dependencies. In the simplest case, you just use a build-rule with sources and a target:

```
def build(bld):
    bld(
        rule = 'cat ${SRC[0].abspath()} > ${TGT}',
        source = ['hello.txt', 'there.txt'],
        target = 'out.txt'
    )
```

As you can see, `out.txt` will be produced by cat:ing `hello.txt` to it and both `hello.txt` and `there.txt` will be seen as the targets dependencies. Here I have hardcoded the dependencies in the wscript, but you would of course call your program that generates the dependencies list as use that.

Comment: Its such an old post that now I have moved on from this, but still, IIRC the problem that I had was adding the dependencies - which were not sources (something similar to `.h` files when we compile a `.c` file, but this was, for a different language, tool)

Comment: My example demonstrates just that. `there.txt` is a dependency even though it is not used by the process. If you mean something else maybe you can clarify?

Comment: ok, I should check back the sources, cant remember exactly where I was stuck! :(